# Can you explain the following quote: "All evil is good become cancerous"

Tags: paradox, reason

I am unable to find illustrative examples to satisfy the above-mentioned quote by Isaac Asimov.

Comment: See  very similar question 'All evil is potential vitality in need of transformation?' https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/51482/all-evil-is-potential-vitality-in-need-of-transformation/51484#51484

Comment: Could you provide a source for the quote (i..e., where Asimov said it in print or in speech; or, if you don't have a direct reference for that, then, where *you* found the quote before asking about it here)? One way to better understand the saying and possible examples would be to read it in context.

Comment: [Shankara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_evil_in_Hinduism) *develops the argument that God is not the Brahman, and that "a loving and good God could not have created the universe", a position held by Advaita Vedanta school... Vaishnavism ... asserts that Vishnu only creates potentialities.* So evil is from karmic ignorance and wrong knowledge hold by agent out of all the created potentialities which is good since they're from God. In Lurianic Kabbalah successive self-withdrawl of the Ein Sof down through the Worlds reducing the infinite light (good) to finite (evil) at lower levels.

Comment: I have looked for an Asimov source for this quote and none is available. Instead I found Poul Anderson said it in "The Corridors of Time" (1965) which you can verify on Google books. This quote is probably misattributed to Asimov. Please do not repeat fake uncited information. If a quote lacks a source, you should not repeat it.

Answer (score 0):

> "All evil is good become cancerous"

Read literally, it means there all evil was at one time good, with the latent figure of that being almost a parasitic growth, one which kills us - presumably our 'soul'. It's probably punning on 'becoming' "(of clothing) looking good on someone." Both have the same root, of to be or do something, which may be quite fanciful here, who knows?

Is it the case? Asimov was a vocal critic of the bible, as well as being a scifi writer. There may well be some truth to a claim like

- the road to hell is paved with good intentions.

On the plus side, doctor, tell me how long I have...

---

More generally, you could see it as a denial of original sin, which was important to the first modern writers (Baudelaire etc.), so it probably inhabits that strange ground between modern and post modern.

> But your iniquities have made a separation between you and your God,
> and your sins have hidden his face from you so that he does not hear.

Isiah 59:2 (nb I don't read the bible). This sits quite nicely with the image of the popular author as God making.

Answer (score -1):

The idea that "All evil is good become cancerous" is the logical corollary to an aphorism that Asimov (as a writer) would have known well: that "every man is the hero of his own story". Consider anyone we might consider *bad* or *evil*, be it a milquetoast villain like an overbearing boss or a nasty ex-spouse, or someone as far outside the pale as a serial killer or a brutal dictator. We don't understand them (which is part of why we think they are evil), but they understand themselves. They have reasons, they have goals, they have desires: they see themselves as performing vital, necessary, and 'good' tasks, and it's possible (even likely) that they think *we* are bad or evil for not sharing their goals. That nasty boss isn't nasty just for the fun of it; that nasty boss is nasty because his employees aren't conforming to what ***he*** thinks is good and right, and feels responsible for whipping them into shape.

It's a mistake to assume that there is some overarching conflict between 'good' and 'evil' in the world. Where we see conflict, it lies between different people/groups who think different things are good; the other side is called 'evil' in reflection, but that use of the term is almost meaningless.

Evil **acts** — the actions and behaviors we see that leave us shocked and appalled — are invariably the result of someone whose common sense and reason have been warped by a desperate, unrequited fixation on achieving what they believe is good. People who murder abortion doctors or burn down black churches, the [Oklahoma City bombers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oklahoma_City_bombing), the 9/11 terrorists, the 1/6 insurrectionists: the common thread in all these cases is people who have become so enraged, disoriented, and frustrated by their inability to achieve what they subjectively believe is 'good' that they are willing to act in ways that they would otherwise consider objectively evil. The intrinsic moral common sense that all humans share has been corrupted and warped to the service of a cause, without the recognition that the cause itself is perverted and debased by such corrupted acts.

Comment: Here is the conclusion I have drawn after reading your reply: - When good fixates itself on the cause alone and disregards the evilness of the plan, it has become evil. Kindly correct any mistakes in my interpretation.

Comment: @KannuIndia: Well, caveat: I don't really subscribe to the concepts of 'good' and 'evil' the way they are normally used. I'd personally put it in more karmic terms: The more one fixates on attaining a desire, the more collateral damage one wreaks in the world. That could be an immoral 'ends justifies the means' situation, or an amoral 'bull in a china shop' thing, but the issue is how much (karmic) wreckage one leaves in one's wake while pursuing a Good. Other people see all that wreckage as 'evil' but the person causing it only sees the 'good' he's chasing.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your reply to this question has really given so much clarity to me. :)

Comment: This is not an Asimov quote and you should have checked for a legitimate source before answering. Online quote anthologies that don't even list the work it appears in are not legitimate sources.

Comment: @causative: The question is about the quote, not about the author. but I see your point.

Comment: It appears in the Poul Anderson novel, "The Corridors of Time" (1965) and there it doesn't have the meaning you ascribed to it. It was about an *organization* that once did good, but has since turned evil. It's not about the inscrutable motivation of individuals. It's more about bureaucratic decay over time.